# How to connect QGIS to a WMS-C with python?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I would like to connect my QGis to a WMS-C server when my python plugin load.
How can I do that ?

BTW, the method:
    addRasterLayer
do not seams to handle WMS-C layer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 1.7.4 you can use:

```py
qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer( "tiled=256;256;0.703125;0.3515625;0.17578125;0.087890625;0.0439453125;0.02197265625;0.010986328125;0.0054931640625;0.00274658203125;0.001373291015625;0.0006866455078125;0.00034332275390625;0.000171661376953125;0.0000858306884765625;0.00004291534423828125;0.00002145767211914062;0.00001072883605957031;0.00000536441802978516;0.00000268220901489258;0.00000134110450744629,url=http://labs.metacarta.com/wms-c/tilecache.py?", "Metacarta basic WMS-C layer", "wms", ["basic"], [""], "image/png", "EPSG:4326" )
```

The `tiled=` argument consists of tile width, height and the available resolutions.